# type of Sympy symbolic expressions

Tags: types, sympy

I have a function that should only accept arguments of type type, as when you call

```
type(type)
```

but the output of

```
type(type(sympy.symbols("a"))
```

is not `type`, but rather `sympy.core.assumptions.ManagedProperties`.

I wonder if there is a way to make it so that the `type(symbols("a"))` throws out `type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ManagedProperties` class is itself a subclass of `type`:

```
In [7]: type(type(symbols("a"))).__mro__
Out[7]: 
(sympy.core.assumptions.ManagedProperties,
 sympy.core.core.BasicMeta,
 type,
 object)
```

In that sense it is already `type` or rather there shouldn't need to be any reason to distinguish it from `type`:

```
In [8]: isinstance(type(symbols("a")), type)
Out[8]: True

In [9]: issubclass(type(type(symbols("a"))), type)
Out[9]: True
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the .__mro__ attribute helped me.